# Can we attain liberation through having Bhakti on a normal person?

Tags: bhakti

Usually Bhakti is referred to unconditional love towards God, Worshiping God, Chanting his name and thinking of him day and night. And a bhakta who is completely Devoted to God in mind, body and soul will be liberated.

My question is, can someone have that intensity of bhakti towards his/her mother, father, husband, wife or any person other than God and get moksha?

Comment: It is common to misunderstand `bakthi` and `bakthi yoga` are same, where the former is what you are referring to while the latter is the one that leads to liberation.

Comment: I think there is an example of Shravan Kumar, who had the same bhakti towards his parents and he is also said to be liberated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to develop intense love for a human and still attain liberation. [Here](http://www.estudantedavedanta.net/gospel_srk.pdf) (search page 453) are words spoken by Sri Ramakrishna, quoting an incident where some women asked him about their salvation:

> The women then asked me if they would have salvation.  'Yes,' I said, 'if you are absolutely faithful to one man and **look on him as your God**.  But you cannot be liberated if you live with five men.'

Therefore as per the great saint, it is possible to develop deep devotion for a human. This way, considering the person as your God, the mind of the lover is purified and the salvation is attained.